# Non-Wireless device needs wireless capabilities

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a device that I am currently connecting to my local network via a serial port to LAN converter (NPort 5110) 
I am looking for a piece of hardware I can connect to the group that will allow WLAN communication for my device.

So the setup is

> [device]-[nport] ==lan cable== [router]

and I would like

> [device]-[nport]-[wlan-enabling-device] >> wifi connection >> [router]

problem is i'm not even sure such devices exist and if they do i'm unsure what they are called or where to look for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

woulndnt a standard ethernet to wireless bridge suit your purpose?  something like [this](http://homestore.cisco.com/en-us/adapters/linksys-WET610N_stcVVproductId65221232VVcatId543809VVviewprod.htm?icid=All-Linksys-Products-Bridges&src2=home_linksys_bridge_all)?

Answer (score 1):

There are serial-wifi devices that would be a nearly a drop-in replacement for your serial-lan device.  For example, the manufacturer of your current devices also offers the NPort W2150/2250

Alternately, many wrt54gl-stype home wifi access points capable of running an alternative firmware can be operated "backwards" in wifi client mode where they use the wifi as the upstream provider for a lan formed from their wired-ethernet ports.

Comment: unfortunately the NPort 2150/2250 (I've purchased both) do not work with my device. I have contacted MOXA about the issue and they have been unable to provide assistance. Furthermore, 90% of our clients currently use the NPort 5110, So I am looking for an inexpensive solution to give them wireless access. But thankyou for your answer, I will look into the access points running in different modes.